# Excel VBA - Link a Label and a Checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following userform:

[image]

Using the code below I can save the names of each selected checkbox into a sheet. The value will be saved in the same column, but on different rows (of course), as more than 1 checkbox can be selected.

```
Dim indProdWs As Worksheet
Dim ctl As Control
Dim i As Long

Set indProdWs = tWb.Worksheets("INDICATION-PRODUCT")

i = 4
' This is the row where i want to save the first value
For Each ctl In seg_multipage.Pages(1).Controls
   If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
        If ctl.Value = True Then
            indProdWs.Cells(i, 9) = ctl.Caption: i = i + 1
        End If
    End If
Next ctl
```

However, as you can see in the first image, for each row of products there's a label.

This is what I want to accomplish:

If Product 22 in the second row is selected, then I want the name to be saved on the cell with the following format:

Label2 - Product22

Or if Product 51 in the second row is selected:

Label 5 - Product 51

As you can see, the label number **always** matches the first digit of the product. I tried using that as a variable, but I haven't been successful.

Thank you for any help you can give me!

Comment: is the name actually "Product22" or this just an example?

Comment: @SiddharthRout just an example, but the format is similar. An actual name is seg_cb_selInd_22 (for example).

Comment: If you name all your checkboxes as `cb_LineNumber_ProductNumber` and your labels as `lbl_LineNumber` then you can translate each checkbox name to a label name. `Me.Controls("lbl_" & Split(checkBoxNameHere, "_")(1)).Caption`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is the name actually "Product22" or this just an example? – Siddharth Rout 6 mins ago

> @SiddharthRout just an example, but the format is similar. An actual name is seg_cb_selInd_22 (for example). – soraia635 1 min ago

Is this what you are trying?

Change the `For - Next` code to the below

```
For Each ctl In seg_multipage.Pages(1).Controls
   If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
        If ctl.Value = True Then
            indProdWs.Cells(i, 9) = Controls("seg_l_selInd_" & _
                                    GetNumber(ctl.Name)).Caption & _
                                    " - " & _
                                    ctl.Name
            i = i + 1
        End If
    End If
Next ctl
```

and then add this function to your code

```
Private Function GetNumber(s As String)
    Dim numb As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        Select Case Mid(s, i, 1)
        Case 0 To 9
            numb = Mid(s, i, 1)
            Exit For
        End Select
    Next
    
    GetNumber = numb
End Function
```

**Note:** This function assumes that you will pass an Alphanumeric string to it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I may have not explained myself well, I apologize! All the labels have different captions.

For example, in the second row the label caption is ABC, but the label name is label_2. So, for Product21 (for example) I would need ABC - Product21.

Comment: In that case you will have to extract the 1st number from the checkbox caption. So clarify this me. For example if the name is `Sid123` then we need to extract `1` from it?

Comment: For example, the first row has 1 Label and 4 products. The label caption is SID. If I select Product 11, I need "SID-Product11".

I mentioned the numbers because I thought it could be a way of matching the labels and the checkboxes in the same row.

Comment: Label is not a problem here. I am talking about the checkbox caption. If the checkbox caption is `Sid123` then we need to extract `1` from it? so it becomes `Label1 - Sid123`?

Comment: Oh, the checkbox caption is Porto (for example). The checkbox name, on the other hand,  is Product11 (for example). So yes, the first digit is the one we need to use.

Comment: Then you need `Ctl.Name` and nto `Ctl.Caption`. I have updated the post. Refresh once to see the changes. Let me know if that is what you wanted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226888/discussion-between-soraia635-and-siddharth-rout).